# Center an image bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, center

I'm using Bootstrap and I want to center an image but I don't know how to do it :/

Here's the HTML

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="./img/logo.png" /></a>
    </div>
```

So I have on my navbar an image and I want to center it I tried in CSS

```
.navbar-brand img{
        width: 83px;
        height: 57px;
        margin-left : 50%;
    }
```

The image doesn't move at all

Answer (score 0):

There are loads of ways to do this, you can use

```
text-align:center;
```

to center elements or

```
margin-left:auto; 
margin-right:auto;
```

This is really basic CSS, you should definitely check the [documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp) before.

Comment: Thanks you I forgot to mention my older CSS code, I tried to use the text-align center tag and it doesn't work, same thing for margin-left|right. I guess it's because of bootstrap framework and so I'm looking for the right way to do it with Bootstrap.

Comment: If bootstrap is over-riding your margins auto, include an !important tag.

Comment: @Beben You can easily overwrite bootstrap, I think you're missing out some CSS rules.

Comment: For clarification: using an !important tag is ideal if this is just for a specific website or proprietary application because it does not remove your Bootstrap from the development cycle and it's quick to implement.  If this is something that you are developing for other developers to build on such as a CMS plugin, you should try to find a way to execute your CSS downstream of your bootstrap.  Modifying your Bootstrap should be done as a last resort, because it removes it from the development cycle.

Comment: @Nosajimiki I disagree, !important has to be used carefuly since it can overwrite your css inside media queries, you can avoid using !important by using the same css tags as bootstrap's tag.

Comment: @Lindow In many cases, I would agree with you, but if he is trying to center his image as a universal rule, over-riding the media queries is probably the point.  I guess it all depends on exactly what he is trying to accomplish here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.navbar-brand img{
    width: 83px;
    height: 57px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

"margin-left:50%" centers the left boundary of your image. "margin: 0 auto;" says put and equal and maximum margin on both the right and left side of my element.  if you need actual margins on the top/bottom you can use the 4-property method which might look like this:

```
margin: 10px auto 20px auto;
```